Can dark matter in neutron stars cause the formation of naked singularities?
I've been studying the concept of dark core collapse, particularly as discussed in the paper "Low Mass Naked Singularities from Dark Core Collapse" on arXiv. The paper explores the idea that dark matter can accumulate in the cores of neutron stars, potentially leading to the formation of tiny collapsed objects. These objects might not always form black holes but could instead result in naked singularities, depending on the initial conditions and properties of the dark matter.
What specific conditions within neutron stars could disrupt or complicate this dark matter accumulation process? Are there scenarios where the accumulation might fail to reach the critical density required for collapse?

This feels rather open-ended, since it hinges on the dark matter properties used. It is easy to limit accumulation if the cross section is too small, for example. And since especially the naked singularity formation hinges on the matter having pretty exotic properties and they even invoke a potentially nontrivially non-homogeneous collapse as a cause, it feels like anything could happen and all sorts of things could prevent it.

@AndersSandberg No, wait, this is crazy! I really never thought you would comment on my post. I read your post about Aestivation hypothesis, Whole Brain Emulation, and I even wrote a separate post about Blueberry Earth on my blog. I am one of those people who share your interests and admire your curiosity. I am so happy to meet you!

It is a small world! Great to meet you here too. Now we need to figure out the question.

What is the mechanism for dark matter accumulation without electromagnetic interactions?

According to the paper, non-self-annihilating DM particles  lose energy due to the scattering with the baryonic matter of the host. For example, in case of the neutron star, the DM particles lose energy due to the scattering with the neutron. The captured DM particles are thermally distributed in a very small region of the core of the host due to the large baryon density. For neutron stars, the DM reaches thermal equilibrium with the neutrons, and the captured DM particles quickly occupy a very small region near the core of the host"

@Lagrangiann Scattering is interaction. Essentially the point of the paper is, if particles interacting stronger gravitationally than electromagnetically existed, then they could form black holes smaller than from normal matter. Fine, there is nothing unusual about this, but no such particles have been observed anyway despite extensive efforts. (Perhaps nature has good reasons for gravitational interactions being weaker than electromagnetic.) And the paper doesn’t seem to have any tangible arguments for a naked singularity, but only “could be”.


Can dark matter in neutron stars cause the formation of naked singularities ?

The answer depends on what you mean by "can".
It seems plausible that if you postulate certain specific properties for dark matter (as the linked paper does) then you can show that dark matter with these properties can in principle give rise to a naked singularity. But to turn this academic exercise into something physically meaningful you have to do one of two things:
(a) find direct evidence that demonstrates that dark matter exists and has the properties that you postulate, and hence could in theory produce a naked singularity
or (b) find evidence for the existence of a naked singularity, and show that dark matter with the properties that you postulate is a likely route to the formation of this naked singularity (you would have to rule out other explanations for the naked singularity, such as a black hole rotating very rapidly).
Since we have evidence for neither (a) nor (b), the answer to your question is "yes in theory, but not as far as we know in our own universe".

Even before (a) and (b), one would need to prove that “dark matter” exists. So far “dark matter” is but an excuse for why the gravitational theory fails at the galaxy scale.

@safesphere True. I have amended my answer.
